# Asterisk Connection not working

Tags: voip, asterisk, configuration, sip

I have installed Asterisk on VirtualBox by following the steps from [here](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Installing+AsteriskNOW). Everything went ok until I got to navigate to an IP to configure Asterisk using FreePBX: 10.0.2.15 (Shouldn't be something like 192.168.x.y?? ). However, when I navigated to that url from outside of VirtualBox, that url pointed to nothing. 
Also I am logged in as root@localhost. Should I be logged in as root@server? 
I have also validated the installation as described [here](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Validating+Your+AsteriskNOW+Installation) and everything went well.

I am a complete beginner at Asterisk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) VirtualBox isn't really suitable for anything production-grade.  Use VMware or KVM instead.

2) Your problem is probably because your Virtual Machine is using the NAT network adapter type, and you should set it to Bridged, and reboot your virtual machine.  Then the VM will get an IP address on the rest of the network, in your case, 192.168.x.x.

You could also forward the ports required for Asterisk to work, through Virtualbox so that you can use the 10.x.y.z address, but this will only be available from your workstation, and isn't ideal.

Use bridged mode.  Always.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and accurate answer. May I also ask what is the difference between 192.168.x.x and 10.x.y.z ? What makes 192.168.x.x address so special and what is designed for? (Complete novice in networking as well)

Comment: There are 3 blocks of network space allocated in RFC1918 for private use.  They're 10.0.0.0/8 (16,777,216 addresses), 172.16.0.0/12 (1,048,576 addresses), and 192.168.0.0/16 (65,536 addresses).  They'll never be routed onto the public internet.

Comment: More information in a human-readable format on RFC1918 can be found here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network